# Asp.net mvc call pop-up window with passed parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am passing some parameters from my view to read it to my controller and its already working properly.

**Question:** Is it possible to call my view as pop-up window rather than load it on the same page?

Currently I am using this call from my index:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(
 "Update",
 "OpDiffSelected",
 new { getOP = @item.op, getOp_desc = @item.op_desc, getDoc_id = item.doc_id, getTitle = item.title, getOp_dif = item.op_dif }
                       )
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult OpDiffSelected(String getOP, String getOp_desc, String getDoc_id, String getTitle, int getOp_dif)
        {
            storeSelectedOP_Diff obj = new storeSelectedOP_Diff
            {
                op = getOP,
                op_desc = getOp_desc,
                doc_id = getDoc_id,
                title = getTitle,
                op_dif = getOp_dif
            };

            return View(obj);
        }
```

And here is my view which loads on the same page:

```
@model userInfo.Models.storeSelectedOP_Diff

<div>
    <h4>Update OP</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            OP
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.op)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            OP Desc
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.op_desc)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>    
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "OpDiffIndex")
</p>
```

Any suggestion or comments to transfer it as pop-up. TIA

Comment: are you using boot-strap? : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal

Comment: Use ajax to call the server method, and then load the returned partial view into a modal in the success callback

Comment: could you give some initial sample or idea how can I inject that to my code?

Comment: Take a look for these examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336834/mvc-passing-parameters-from-view-to-popup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113950/use-actionlink-to-open-modal-and-pass-parameter-in-mvc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714917/asp-mvc-passing-value-into-modal-window.